# When creating a linter, what is the expected output format?

Tags: javascript, parsing, command-line-interface

Linting is an invaluable technique when crafting code. Yet I find myself wanting to understand the process of linting more. To do this, I am building a basic static code analysis tool with node.

What the linter should do is perform a regex check and if the regex matches, throw an error (or warning depending on the user's config).

I understand that linters traditionally parse code and some even execute checks on an AST, but I want to avoid this entirely. I also understand that my method is bypassing nearly every important part of linting by avoiding the parsed syntax altogether.

---

The goal is to be able to write a few dead-simple checks and have this as an accessory linter for rapid prototyping. (example: put `^$\n^$` into my linter config and an error would be thrown for two continuous blank lines)

The part of the process that seems undocumented is what type of output is expected to the command line. Here is example output from [xo](http://github.com/sindresorhus/xo):

```
/Users/dawsonbotsford/code/regexLinter/cli.js
  42:9   error  Expected indentation of 6 space characters but found 8   indent
  43:9   error  Expected indentation of 6 space characters but found 8   indent
  43:32  error  Missing semicolon                                        semi
```

And eslint example output:

```
/Users/dawsonbotsford/code/regexLinter/cli.js
  3:1  error  Parsing error: The keyword 'const' is reserved
```

How would I mimic this output with the correct types of shell errors/warnings such that it would be pluggable into sublime-contrib plugins, CI servers, etc.?

Comment: Freeing linter developers from this kind of work is one of the goals of [coala](http://coala-analyzer.org/). I haven't implemented anything via their framework yet, but they seem to be very active and support many languages and output formats already.

Comment: I looked at the coala site.  There's lots of talk about "framework" but it all seems pretty pointless; there is basically zero support for doing *analysis*, which is the hard part.  To me this appears as if somebody claimed they had the ideal scheme for implementing AI, and offered you LISP.   Yes, LISP can be pretty nice, but what is left out is any actual AI machinery.  For an alternative view, see http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to be pluggable the simplest you can do is write a plugin for [**ESLint**](https://eslint.org) if you need to capture formatting issues. If you want to transform code use [**Putout**](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout), the tool I’m working on, it also has a plugin for **ESLint** so the messages you are going to show, will be accessible in terminal, IDE, CI etc.

> The part of the process that seems undocumented is what type of output is expected to the command line.

The thing is command line don't care about output any CLI tool makes, what matter is ability for the user to understand the output as fast as possible. For this purpose **ESLint** has lot's of [formatters](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/formatters/). Because of pluggable nature and documented format, anybody can write formatters for the cases they need. For example [`json`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/formatters/#json) formatter helps to parse output of **ESLint** by any other tool, and show it in the way you need.

[**Putout**](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout) has similar way of using [formatters](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout#-formatters), it shows progress bar, by default, but on CI you don't need it, so it switches to `dump` formatter, which only shows end results.

So if you need **ESLint** support, or you want to use existing formatter to show your errors, you need to support its API, for example [`@putout/formatter-eslint`](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/master/packages/formatter-eslint#putoutformatter-eslint-) gives ability for **Putout** to use any existing **ESLint** formatter, since it convert it's output format to the one **ESLint** uses.

> How would I mimic this output with the correct types of shell errors/warnings

One of the ways to mimic default output of ESLint is using [`table`](https://github.com/gajus/table#readme) library, I made it this way in [@putout/formatter-dump](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/master/packages/formatter-dump#putoutformatter-dump-):

```js
for (const {name, places} of json.errors) {
    const line = buildLine(places);
        
    output.push([
        underline(name),
        table(line, {
            border: getBorderCharacters('void'),
                drawHorizontalLine: () => false,
            }),
    ].join('\n'));
}
    
output.push(bold(redBright(`✖ ${errorsCount} errors in ${filesCount} files`)));
output.push(bold(redBright('  fixable with the `--fix` option')));
```

It builds table with invisible borders and all data in it.